# Why is that a question can be answered with several theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations, models

This may be silly and I am sorry for that but it is confusing me. My teacher was teaching us about *path of electrons* around a nucleus. He told us that many theories have been proposed about path of an electron and the latest theory is somehow different from saying that electron revolves in a circular path around nucleus. Even though he used the circular-path theory (temporarily called so) to demonstrate other phenomenons such as Ionization Potential, vaporization etc and it all seems logical. He also said that other theories concerning to electronic path can also be used to demonstrate these phenomenons but I am using this since this is simpler.

But how this is possible? I am thinking that these things must be working under a single theory (may be one among them or one uncovered so far) naturally then why a question can be answered with several theories completely logically.

Comment: *"I am thinking that God must have created all that under a single theory/law"* To paraphrase Pascal: You may well think that, but science has no need of that hypothesis. All scientific theories are *approximate models of reality*, not unchangable truth set in stone. Also, this is less a question about physics and more about philosophy of knowledge/science.

Answer (score 1):

A "theory" is nothing more than a *recipe* to describe a natural phenomenon.

There can be many theories to describe the same thing, just as I can use different words to describe the same object.

Theories can be very different from one another for several reasons.
They can describe the same exact phenomenology with different formalism (different words for the same object), or can describe different aspect of that phenomenon (using more words to better describe the characteristics of the object).

Comment: "They can describe the same exact phenomenon with different formalism" . Of course that happens otherwise theories can't be said different.  There is nothing very new in your answer. This is all I have already mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Sufyan theories *can* very well describe different phenomenology for the the phenomenon, like general relativity describing an apple falling from a tree just as well as newtonian gravity, but being able to better describe other things, like the motion of mercury. The answer to your question is that a theory is a way to *describe* something , nothing more and nothing less. The only difference in the way we describe objects in the everyday life is that physical phenomenon are better describe by math rather than words.. At least sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Because a theory only covers what is known at the moment. In the future new features and behaviour may be discovered to apply in certain situations. A new theory must then be made that covers the old theory AND the new discoveries and takes it all into account.

For example, the original Bohr model of the atom as electrons in circular orbits orbiting the nucelus appears to lack certain details in certain situations and had some flaws in expaining certain things. So the quantum theory has arrived to explain that. Therefore the Bohr model is not accurate in all areas. Even so it is still used.

Why? Because it is still usable within a certain scale (where quantum effects are so tiny that they are negligible). So we can use a theory or model as long as we know the range of application of it. Within the range, it may be utilized, and outside of the range we must remind ourselves that now the previously insignificant behaviours are not insignificant anymore, and another model (if it has been made) must be used instead at this scale.

Comment: @Steven but sometimes the new theory is completely different from older one.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem How do you mean different? Of course a new theory may  or may not be wrong until experimentally verified. But one would never make a theory that cannot explain what is already established (otherwise the new theory would already have failed...)

Comment: I have read somewhere that a theory declares that everything is a vibration i.e. we just feel it but we deal everything as mass according to another theory. NASA considers flat earth theory. It is of course completely different from sphere earth theory (temp. called so).

Comment: @SufyanNaeem I guess you are refering to string theory. This is not within my scope of knowledge, unfortunately, but the point remains the same. This theory might have been established to try to explain some farout cases and behaviour where the current view and theory has shown not to be enough. The current view is not wrong - just only applicable within a certain range.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem If you are going to be a physicist you have to have clear in mind that physics is about observations of nature and experiments fitted with mathematical models that have predictive power. New mathematical models may appear, ovelapping in phase space, but they have to be consistent with the data. Otherwise one is talking of science fiction, not science, or mathematics and philosophy, not physics.

Comment: @Steeven don't you think *flat earth theory and earth-is-a-sphere* are totally different things? And what about *vibration and mass*? Aren't they totally different?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Flat Earth theory... Well... If you make a theory from your observations, then it isn't settled that this theory holds for other areas that you have not yet investigated! Earth might look flat from our eyes' perspective and from "local" measurements, so all models and theories can very well work WITHIN this range. Later on the Earth was found to be round... So a new model was established - it still works in the local area, as the large curvature appears flat over shorter distances, but also it correctly models the whole Earth. And has never since been experimentally disproven...

Comment: @SufyanNaeem - Please provide a link to justify "NASA considers flat earth theory" My first impression is that you do not understand what NASA thinks.

Comment: Okay @WhatRoughBeast but there is still a question that says, "aren't vibration and mass entirely different things?".